# Flutter: Expand row widget inside column in stack

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a CustomScrollView and inside this widget I have SliverGrid. In SliverGrid I am showing my custom widget :

```
   return Stack(
      children: [
        Image.asset("assets/icons/folder_icon.png"),
        Positioned(
          top: 30,
          left: 10,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  InkWell(
                    child: Icon(Icons.add),
                    onTap: onTapSync,
                  ),
                  InkWell(
                    child: Icon(Icons.sync),
                    onTap: onTapSync,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Text(
                title,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    )
```

the result is:

[image]

How can I expand the Row widget according to the folder Icon so that 2 icons are located in the left and right folder image?

I don't want to use for example SizedBox(width: xx) between 2 icons. or extract icons from the column.

Comment: wrap `Column` with a `SizedBox`with width equals to the folder icon width, then add a Spacer between the two icons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets try this:

```
    Positioned(
      top: 30,
      left: 10,
      right: 0,

      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              InkWell(
                child: Icon(Icons.add),
                onTap: onTapSync,
              ),
              InkWell(
                child: Icon(Icons.sync),
                onTap: onTapSync,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    )
```

Comment: Yes,I got error, If you have suggestions please add a comment .

Comment: Did you try to wrap you stack to sizebox which has all screen width using media query

Comment: If that also not work then try to give Positioned right value to 0

Comment: Positioned right value to 0 works. I fixed your response

Comment: Thanks for fixing, i was on mobile so couldn't reply in proper format